# How to add shapes equidistantly along a curved path in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, vector, bezier-curve

I have a Bezier curve along which I would like to add shapes at a nominal number of equidistant points between its two nodes.

So far, I have selected the two bounding nodes of the curve and added intermediate nodes between them. I have then used those nodes with snap functionality to position the shapes. This produced precisely the result I was looking for, the caveat being that I could add only 2ⁿ–1 nodes (1, 3, 7, 15, ...)

If I added enough nodes, I could theoretically accommodate any odd number equidistantly, but no even number. I would like to add an even number.

*Does Inkscape provide any way of placing a nominal number of equally-spaced new nodes between two existing nodes (instead of one at a time), OR is there a better way to approach this problem?*

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'Extensions → Modify Path → Add Nodes...' extension lets you divide curves into any number of nodes. You can even specify a desired segment length instead of number of divisions. Keep in mind that the resulting segments may all be a little shorter depending on the length of the original path.

[image: 'Add Notes' extension dialog]

Comment: Thank you. That worked a treat!

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to add shapes, then it's possible to do this without adding any nodes. You could use the Pattern Along a Path LPE.

Basically, set the Pattern Copies to Repeated Stretched, then you can adjust the number of copies by increasing or decreasing the spacing.

Here's an example

[image]

Comment: That was not a function that I was aware of, thank you. It is probably the more complex solution to my specific problem, but I will definitely remember that for future projects.